# SearchView expand throws null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am testing application in Samsung Galaxy Tab (P7500) (android 4.0.4) and I am get this error on trying expand default `SearchView` widget in action bar. Before 4.0.4 update my application works very well.

Error log:

```
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.widget.SearchView.adjustDropDownSizeAndPosition(SearchView.java:1244)
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.widget.SearchView.access$300(SearchView.java:92)
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.widget.SearchView$5.onLayoutChange(SearchView.java:336)
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11486)
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1644)
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1633)
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1417)
09-29 14:18:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(2814):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
....
```

I tried to hunt this error. I checked 4.0.3 an d 4.0.4 source (API 15), and `android.widget.SearchView` file's line 1244 method end: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/android/widget/SearchView.java?av=f

I think samsung modified this source file.

After that I tried to determine where is null pointer by using original 4.0.4 source and debug info. I found problem can be here:

```
mQueryTextView.getDropDownBackground().getPadding(dropDownPadding);
```

`mQueryTextView.getDropDownBackground()` returns null, because `SearchView.this.mQueryTextView.mPopup.mPopup.mBackground` is null.

I am not sure this is exactly error, because samsung has been modified source code. And I don't know what I can do next.

This is my ActionBar menu XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" />

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/favorites" 
        android:title="Favourites"
        android:icon="@drawable/favorites">

    </item>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/recent" 
        android:title="Recent"
        android:icon="@drawable/recent">

    </item>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/downloaded" 
        android:title="Downloaded"
        android:icon="@drawable/downloaded">

    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be related to styles being applied to the EditText in the action bar SearchView.

You can fix this by removing any style you have applied to EditText such as:

res/values/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/editor</item>
```

Then go to each EditText view in your layout XML and apply the style directly:

```
<EditText style="@style/editor" />
```

Comment: For SO Moderators : this answer is duplicated : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22295139/2178259](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22295139/2178259)