# Android Action Bar SearchView NullPointerException adjustDropDownSizeAndPosition

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, searchview

The problem occurs when interacting with the SearchView or when the activity with the Searchview loads. When using `setIconifiedByDefault(true)` the problem occurs after the activity loads when interacting with the SearchView, but when using `setIconifiedByDefault(false)` the problem occurs when the activity loads.

The following error is output in LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.SearchView.adjustDropDownSizeAndPosition(SearchView.java:1244)
```

Here is the code:

*ExampleActivity.java*

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.example, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        search.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() { 

            @Override 
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { 

                // Perform search

                return true; 

            }

        });

    }

    return true;

}
```

*menu/example.xml*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

*xml/searchable.xml*

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search"
    android:hint="@string/search" >
</searchable>
```

The "search" string used in *searchable.xml* is defined in *values/strings.xml*. Also the *searchable.xml* file is referenced correctly in the activity tag in *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is caused by styles being applied to the `EditText` in the action bar `SearchView`.

You can fix this by removing any style you have applied to `EditText` such as:

*res/values/styles.xml*

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/editor</item>
```

Then go to each `EditText` view in your layout XML and apply the style directly:

```
<EditText style="@style/editor" />
```

Comment: You also have to remove <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/EdiText</item> if you have that... this sucks man